Get the data in the Span class of HTML by Python
I am trying to get the data in one of span class from a website. Currently, I caught the correct position of my data but I can't get the text of  class.
My code:
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

res = requests.get('https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/chainlink/')

soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'lxml')

elements = soup.find_all("span", class_="sc-f70bb44c-0 flfGQp flexStart alignBaseline")
values = soup.find_all("span", class_="sc-f70bb44c-0 jxpCgO base-text")
print(values)


My output:
span class="sc-f70bb44c-0 jxpCgO base-text">$14.22</span
My expectation is get the only "$14.22"

You will not get that output from the code shown

Replace
print(values)

with
for value in values:
    print(value.get_text())


Always check the HTTP status code.
You're calling find_all() which will return a (possibly empty) list.
Try this:
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with requests.get('https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/chainlink/') as res:
    res.raise_for_status()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, features="lxml")
    for span in soup.find_all("span", class_="sc-f70bb44c-0 jxpCgO base-text"):
        print(span.text)

Output:
$14.24

